# Are the sets in a basis open in the topology the basis generates?

Tags: general-topology

A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a set $X$ is called a *basis* if:

1. For each $x\in X$, $\exists B\in\mathcal{B}$ with $x\in B$.
2. If $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ for $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$, then $\exists B_3\in\mathcal{B}$ with $x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the topology on $X$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$:

- $U \subset X$ is open (that is, $U \in \mathcal{J}$) if $\forall x\in U\; \exists B\in\mathcal{B}:x\in B\text{ and }B\subset U$.

**So are basis elements open?**

Let $U\in\mathcal{B}$. I need to show that $\forall x\in U$ there exists a basis element that contains $x$ and this basis element must itself be contained in $U$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, that would __generate__ the indiscreet topology.

Comment: Right, I misread what you were defining.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews your comment was a good example though! I wish you hadn't have deleted it (I thought (okay not for long - I am proud to say) about it and concluded it generated the familiar indiscreet topology)

Comment: It was a pointless comment, and I don't like leaving litter on this site. I thought you were defining a "basic for a topology $\tau$," not a general basis which can be used to define a topology. A subtle distinction.

Answer (score 2):

It has just occurred to me that if we choose $U$ as the basis element then $U\subset U$ and that works to show it is open.

If this were not the case (we demanded a proper subset) then we could always find a smaller basis element, thus we couldn't have a finite basis, so at some point we must accept the relation is not strict.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. For each $x\in U$, take $B=U$. Better to use $B\subseteq U$ in the definition above, because it is clearer - some people read $\subset$ as $\subsetneq$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the basis elements are open.

A set $X$ and a collection $\mathfrak B$ of subsets of $X$, which satisfy the given properties. **Only then** do we define the topology $\mathscr T$ using this basis, so until this is done it doesn't make sense to talk about the basis elements of $\mathfrak B$ as being "open".

Now, once we do define our topology, recall that we define a subset $U$ of $X$ to be open if given $x\in U$ there exists $B\in\frak B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. Since this certainly holds when $U=B\in\frak B$, we see that all elements of $\frak B$ are open.

Now starting with some collection of subsets $\frak B$ that generate a topology,  calling this topology $\scr T$. So by what we said above, all basis elements are open in $\scr T$ and there should be no issue.